# Mobile website bug

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm new here and I need some help. I'm developing a mobile website and the client wants somethings that really need jquery. I explained a hundred times, but he really wants somethings that I will need to put the jquery api, but the problem is this:

I need to make a box appears fixed in the top when the user pass in certain point, I do this code:

```
$(function() {
    var $top1= $('.containerPadrao').offset().top + 50;
    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        if ($(window).scrollTop()>$top1) {
            $('.promocaoFixa').fadeIn("fast");
        } else {
            $('.promocaoFixa').fadeOut("fast");
         }
    });
});
```

and the problem is, in the touch mobile the scroll count only when you take your finger out, but if you pass this point when need to go back the page, the content only fade out when you take out the finger or you reach the top of the page, making the wrong thing!